# Running another Task after first Task

Tags: c#, .net, task

I have a simple method like this, but I can't run `runAfter` as follows, but compiler says :

**Error CS1503  Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task' to 'System.Action'**

```
static async Task TaskSyncWithRemote(string subFolder, Task runAfter)
{
    ...
    some code run here
    ...
    // now I want to run "runAfter", but compiler doesn't like it :)
    if (runAfter!=null)
       Task.Run(runAfter);
}
```

Comment: Task.Run() expects an Action delegate as a parameter. you are passing to it an object of type Task, hence the error you read. can you post the code of which runAfter comes from ? i think you can refactor your code there to achieve your end goal

Comment: You should actually state what your question is. We can sort of figure it out, but you have only made statements here. You haven't asked us anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to pass a Task object to Task.Run() method but compiler is telling you can not :) Compiler is a smart guy, you should listen to him. You can pass for example an Action to Task.Run(). However, I think you are more interested in ContinueWith() method

Comment: It would be awesome if you'd show some code to explain how the OP would use `.ContinueWith` in his particular example.

Answer (score 1):

> // now I want to run "runAfter"

`runAfter` is already in progress when you enter this method.

You can (asynchronously) wait for it to *complete*, if you want:

```
static async Task TaskSyncWithRemote(string subFolder, Task runAfter)
{
  ... // Code executed while `runAfter` is in progress.
  await runAfter;
  ... // Code executed after `runAfter` is done.
}
```

If you mean you don't want `runAfter` to *start* until that point, then you will have to change the type of your parameter to `Func<Task>` and invoke it at that time:

```
static async Task TaskSyncWithRemote(string subFolder, Func<Task> runAfter)
{
  ... // Code executed before `runAfter` starts.
  await runAfter();
  ... // Code executed after `runAfter` is done.
}
```

Comment: what if he just created the task using the constructor, it wouldn't be already in progress then

Comment: @SirajMansour: Since there is never a good reason to do that, I assumed that the op did not.

Answer (score -1):

Although it's not recommended. you can call `.Start()` on `runAfter`

```
if (runAfter!=null)
   runAfter.Start();
```

as for why it is not recommended, i suggest this [read](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pfxteam/2010/06/13/task-factory-startnew-vs-new-task-start/).

With the level of detail and context provided about your problem, i can only assume you are doing the following :

```
Task runAfter = new Task(() => /* do something */);

await TaskSyncWithRemote("mySubfolder",runAfter);
```

however a better approach would be to refactor your method `TaskSyncWithRemote` to do its job only, and leave triggering a continuation task to the TaskScheduler through the nice TPL api such as :

```
 await TaskSyncWithRemote("mySubfolder").ContinueWith(() => /* do something */);
```

Comment: Please (1) don't suggest something that isn't recommended, (2) don't link to external sites, and (3) you should try to answer the question being asked.

Comment: @Enigmativity I did answer the question, suggested a valid solution. And warned of the downside. Worst downvote and review i ever saw !

Comment: @Enigmativity and since when there is a rule against external sites ?! Even worse, you want me to answer the question, but in your comment upthere you can't figure out what the question is !

Comment: Sorry, I should have been clearer on the external link. External links are encouraged but only to support content already in your answer - it should be the case that if the link become broken that the answer would be sufficient without it. You should bring the salient points of the linked site into your answer.

Comment: The question can be inferred, but it would aid the quality of the site if the OP were to explicitly ask the question. You haven't explained how calling `.Start()` allows the OP to run a second task **after the first**.

Comment: @Enigmativity he hasn't indicated that he wanted that at all. For all we know he wants to execute some code and then fire his task. he might not have a 'first task' i can see where you are coming from, but you are over assuming for the level of detail provided in the question. and that is why i asked him in my comment to clear out at least where does the parameter task object come from.

Comment: Exactly. Before a good answer to this question can be posted we need to the OP to clear up what he is asking.